# java: Long.parseLong(s,16) and Long.toHexString(l) not inverses?

Tags: java, parsing, long-integer

I get this but yet I don't get it:

```
package com.example.bugs;

public class ParseLongTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long l = -1;
        String s = Long.toHexString(l);
        System.out.println(s);
        long l2 = Long.parseLong(s, 16);
    }   
}
```

This fails with the following:

```
ffffffffffffffff
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ffffffffffffffff"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:410)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
    at com.example.bugs.ParseLongTest.main(ParseLongTest.java:8)
```

presumably because if you literally interpreted 0xffffffffffffffffL, it would not fit in the Long number space, which is signed.

But why does Long.toHexString() produce a string that cannot be parsed by Long.parseLong(), and how do I work around this? (I need a way of getting long values to their hex string representation, and back again)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't specify the radix in `parseLong()`, which would result in NumberFormatException.  Is this a typo on SO or in your original code?

Comment: `Long.toString(long i, int radix)` and `long parseLong(String s, int radix)` however work as expected.

Comment: My original code had the ,16 but that disappeared when I created a test program -- anyway it still gives the exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Long.parseLong(String s, int radix)` doesn't understand two's complement. For negative number it expects minus sign. As bestsss already mentioned you should use `Long.toString(long l, int radix)` to make hex string compatible with this parsing method.

Comment: Ah, I missed the gist of bestsss's comment amid all the radix argument confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug, it is fixed in 1.8, see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4215269

Comment: Not bad - it only took them 13 years. (And I encounter it 2 years later, still not fixed in an Android development environment.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use guava's `UnsignedLongs.parseUnsignedLong(String s, int radix)` if Java 1.8 is not an option.